# Generate Woocommerce Coupon Code As a Product

Tags: woocommerce, invoice, coupon

I have a virtual product called discount package. Upon purchase how can dynamically create a coupon code after payment that can be used no more than 5 times? Can this code be included in the payment confirmation email? Can I track the created coupon code when used for a future purchase?

Comment: Sorry but this question is not clear and understandable… Try to clarify the process in your mind and also in your question, as it seems that there is some Inconsistencies in that process.

Comment: I apologize her are the tangible items I would like help with:
1. How do I allow the purchase of a woocommerce coupon code that is dynamically created after payment that can be used no more than 5 times?
2. How do i include the dynamically created coupon code in the purchase confirmation email?
3. How do I track the coupon code used for a purchase?

Comment: Kindly, for example you can't `"allow the purchase of a woocommerce coupon code"` … instead you are **allowing the purchase of a virtual product** that is going to **create programmatically 2 coupons codes**, that is very different. All your text is very fuzzy and unreadable as it is… Please take your time and re think it again on a white paper before publishing, adding some formatting and make short sentences.